# Why doesn't background image fit the container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this example image comparison tool, I have an original image and a new image that overlays the original.

The New Image is blown up and I don't understand why.

It's a background image that, for reasons of my mvc environment, I need to add it to the HTML as a style attribute and not as a background image in the CSS.

I've tried `background-size: contain;`, `background-size: cover;` and they're not working.

These are the images as they should be seen:

**Original Image:**
[image]

**New Image:**
[image]
Why isn't the **New Image** fitting in the container properly in the comparison tool?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let imageContainer = document.querySelector(".cd-image-container");
  checkPosition(imageContainer);
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    checkPosition(imageContainer);
  });

  let dragElement = document.querySelector(".cd-handle"),
    resizeElement = document.querySelector(".cd-resize-img"),
    container = document.querySelector(".cd-image-container"),
    labelContainer = document.querySelector(
      '.cd-image-label[data-type="original"]'
    ),
    labelResizeElement = document.querySelector(
      '.cd-image-label[data-type="modified"]'
    );

  drags(
    dragElement,
    resizeElement,
    container,
    labelContainer,
    labelResizeElement
  );

  window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    updateLabel(labelResizeElement, resizeElement, "left");
    updateLabel(labelContainer, resizeElement, "right");
  });
});

function checkPosition(container) {
  if (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight * 0.5 > container.offsetTop) {
    container.classList.add("is-visible");
  }
}

function drags(
  dragElement,
  resizeElement,
  container,
  labelContainer,
  labelResizeElement
) {
  dragElement.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    dragElement.classList.add("draggable");
    resizeElement.classList.add("resizable");

    let dragWidth = dragElement.offsetWidth,
      xPosition =
      dragElement.getBoundingClientRect().left + dragWidth - e.pageX,
      containerOffset = container.getBoundingClientRect().left,
      containerWidth = container.offsetWidth,
      minLeft = containerOffset + 10,
      maxLeft = containerOffset + containerWidth - dragWidth - 10,
      leftValue,
      widthValue;

    function onMouseMove(e) {
      leftValue = e.pageX + xPosition - dragWidth;
      if (leftValue < minLeft) {
        leftValue = minLeft;
      } else if (leftValue > maxLeft) {
        leftValue = maxLeft;
      }
      widthValue =
        ((leftValue + dragWidth / 2 - containerOffset) * 100) / containerWidth +
        "%";
      dragElement.style.left = widthValue;
      resizeElement.style.width = widthValue;

      updateLabel(labelResizeElement, resizeElement, "left");
      updateLabel(labelContainer, resizeElement, "right");
    }

    function onMouseUp() {
      dragElement.classList.remove("draggable");
      resizeElement.classList.remove("resizable");
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
      document.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
    }

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);

    e.preventDefault();
  });
}

function updateLabel(label, resizeElement, position) {
  if (position === "left") {
    label.getBoundingClientRect().left + label.offsetWidth <
      resizeElement.getBoundingClientRect().left + resizeElement.offsetWidth ?
      label.classList.remove("is-hidden") :
      label.classList.add("is-hidden");
  } else {
    label.getBoundingClientRect().left >
      resizeElement.getBoundingClientRect().left + resizeElement.offsetWidth ?
      label.classList.remove("is-hidden") :
      label.classList.add("is-hidden");
  }
}
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  header {
    height: 240px;
    line-height: 240px;
  }
  header h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}

.cd-image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 768px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.cd-image-container img {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-image-container {
    margin: 4em auto;
  }
}

.cd-image-label {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: .5em;
  font-size: .889rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(20px);
  transition: transform 0.3s 0.7s, opacity 0.3s 0.7s;
}

.cd-image-label.is-hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.is-visible .cd-image-label {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.cd-resize-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.cd-resize-img .cd-image-label {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
}

.is-visible .cd-resize-img {
  width: 50%;
  animation: cd-bounce-in 0.7s;
}

@keyframes cd-bounce-in {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  60% {
    width: 55%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

.cd-handle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  background-color: #0074ba;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -27px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  cursor: move;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0);
}

.cd-handle.draggable {
  background-color: #004f7e;
  color: white;
}

.is-visible .cd-handle {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.3s 0.7s, opacity 0s 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<figure class="cd-image-container">
  <!-- Original Image -->
  <img src="https://aiseo.ai/products/images/image-gen/1.png" alt="Original Image">
  <span class="cd-image-label" data-type="original">Original</span>
  <!-- New Image -->
  <div class="cd-resize-img" style="background: url('https://static01.nyt.com/images/2022/04/13/science/15SCI-CREATIVITY-vid-image/15SCI-CREATIVITY-vid-image-videoSixteenByNineJumbo1600.jpg') no-repeat left top;">
    <span class="cd-image-label" data-type="modified">Modified</span>
  </div>
  <span class="cd-handle">
    <i class="bi bi-arrows-move"></i>
  </span>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the style attribute in your HTML, use `background-image` rather than just `background`. By using the shorthand property `background`, you’re inadvertently overriding your CSS rules relating to other aspects of the background, including `background-size`.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let imageContainer = document.querySelector(".cd-image-container");
  checkPosition(imageContainer);
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    checkPosition(imageContainer);
  });

  let dragElement = document.querySelector(".cd-handle"),
    resizeElement = document.querySelector(".cd-resize-img"),
    container = document.querySelector(".cd-image-container"),
    labelContainer = document.querySelector(
      '.cd-image-label[data-type="original"]'
    ),
    labelResizeElement = document.querySelector(
      '.cd-image-label[data-type="modified"]'
    );

  drags(
    dragElement,
    resizeElement,
    container,
    labelContainer,
    labelResizeElement
  );

  window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    updateLabel(labelResizeElement, resizeElement, "left");
    updateLabel(labelContainer, resizeElement, "right");
  });
});

function checkPosition(container) {
  if (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight * 0.5 > container.offsetTop) {
    container.classList.add("is-visible");
  }
}

function drags(
  dragElement,
  resizeElement,
  container,
  labelContainer,
  labelResizeElement
) {
  dragElement.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    dragElement.classList.add("draggable");
    resizeElement.classList.add("resizable");

    let dragWidth = dragElement.offsetWidth,
      xPosition =
      dragElement.getBoundingClientRect().left + dragWidth - e.pageX,
      containerOffset = container.getBoundingClientRect().left,
      containerWidth = container.offsetWidth,
      minLeft = containerOffset + 10,
      maxLeft = containerOffset + containerWidth - dragWidth - 10,
      leftValue,
      widthValue;

    function onMouseMove(e) {
      leftValue = e.pageX + xPosition - dragWidth;
      if (leftValue < minLeft) {
        leftValue = minLeft;
      } else if (leftValue > maxLeft) {
        leftValue = maxLeft;
      }
      widthValue =
        ((leftValue + dragWidth / 2 - containerOffset) * 100) / containerWidth +
        "%";
      dragElement.style.left = widthValue;
      resizeElement.style.width = widthValue;

      updateLabel(labelResizeElement, resizeElement, "left");
      updateLabel(labelContainer, resizeElement, "right");
    }

    function onMouseUp() {
      dragElement.classList.remove("draggable");
      resizeElement.classList.remove("resizable");
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
      document.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
    }

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);

    e.preventDefault();
  });
}

function updateLabel(label, resizeElement, position) {
  if (position === "left") {
    label.getBoundingClientRect().left + label.offsetWidth <
      resizeElement.getBoundingClientRect().left + resizeElement.offsetWidth ?
      label.classList.remove("is-hidden") :
      label.classList.add("is-hidden");
  } else {
    label.getBoundingClientRect().left >
      resizeElement.getBoundingClientRect().left + resizeElement.offsetWidth ?
      label.classList.remove("is-hidden") :
      label.classList.add("is-hidden");
  }
}
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  header {
    height: 240px;
    line-height: 240px;
  }
  header h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}

.cd-image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 768px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.cd-image-container img {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-image-container {
    margin: 4em auto;
  }
}

.cd-image-label {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: .5em;
  font-size: .889rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(20px);
  transition: transform 0.3s 0.7s, opacity 0.3s 0.7s;
}

.cd-image-label.is-hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.is-visible .cd-image-label {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.cd-resize-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top left;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.cd-resize-img .cd-image-label {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
}

.is-visible .cd-resize-img {
  width: 50%;
  animation: cd-bounce-in 0.7s;
}

@keyframes cd-bounce-in {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  60% {
    width: 55%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

.cd-handle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  background-color: #0074ba;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -27px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  cursor: move;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0);
}

.cd-handle.draggable {
  background-color: #004f7e;
  color: white;
}

.is-visible .cd-handle {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.3s 0.7s, opacity 0s 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<figure class="cd-image-container">
  <!-- Original Image -->
  <img src="https://aiseo.ai/products/images/image-gen/1.png" alt="Original Image">
  <span class="cd-image-label" data-type="original">Original</span>
  <!-- New Image -->
  <div class="cd-resize-img" style="background-image: url('https://static01.nyt.com/images/2022/04/13/science/15SCI-CREATIVITY-vid-image/15SCI-CREATIVITY-vid-image-videoSixteenByNineJumbo1600.jpg');">
    <span class="cd-image-label" data-type="modified">Modified</span>
  </div>
  <span class="cd-handle">
    <i class="bi bi-arrows-move"></i>
  </span>
</figure>
```